# Reload ListView from its child card in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I I have developed an app which has a `LisView` with cards. I want to reload/refresh the entire `ListView` when user taps an item in `ListView`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> itemsList = [
    "item0",
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
    "item5"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListItemCard(item: itemsList[index]);
              })),
    );
  }
}

class ListItemCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;
  ListItemCard({this.item});
  _ListItemCardState createState() => _ListItemCardState();
}

class _ListItemCardState extends State<ListItemCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        elevation: 10,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Container(
                child:
              Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child:Text(
                  widget.item,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red)));
  }
}
```

I am using Flutter 1.17. I want to make an item selected when on user tap. My issue is while selecting the second item, the item already selected should be unselected. For that i need to update the entire list. My tap event handler is in _ListItemCardState class and invoking setState() will only update the that particular Card in my understanding.

Comment: how about keeping the selectedItem variable as global to class and update it in card item tap with setState{} and use the selectedItem variable in ternary(?:) operator to condition card item selection state in the card view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this , may be you can give each card a unique id while using ListView.builder.
As in ,

1st card has id 0,

2nd card has id 1,

3rd card has id 2,
..
.
and so on.

```
 body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListItemCard(item: itemsList[index],id:index);
          })),
);
```

Now when a card is clicked , you can have a callback function in the _MyHomePageState class,which can be called from the _ListItemCardState class. And passing id of the card as argument .

so , your main class knows which card is clicked, hence rebuild the ui using setState and pass a boolean to ListItemCard saying whether the card is clicked (true) or not(false).

```
child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            bool amIclicked = false;
            if (index == clickedCardId) {
              amIclicked = true;
            }
            return ListItemCard(
              item: itemsList[index],
              id: index,
              callbackFunction: this.callbackFunction,
              amIClicked: amIclicked,
            );
          })
```

and callback function as this:

```
int clickedCardId = -1;
void callbackFunction(cardId) {
setState(() {
  clickedCardId = cardId;
});
```

}

whole code for this for reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> itemsList = [
    "item0",
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
    "item5"
  ];
  int clickedCardId = -1;
  void callbackFunction(cardId) {
    setState(() {
      clickedCardId = cardId;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                bool amIclicked = false;
                if (index == clickedCardId) {
                  amIclicked = true;
                }
                return ListItemCard(
                  item: itemsList[index],
                  id: index,
                  callbackFunction: this.callbackFunction,
                  amIClicked: amIclicked,
                );
              })),
    );
  }
}

class ListItemCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;
  int id;
  var callbackFunction;
  bool amIClicked;
  ListItemCard(
      {this.item, this.id, this.callbackFunction, this.amIClicked = false});
  _ListItemCardState createState() => _ListItemCardState(
      callbackFunction: callbackFunction, id: id, amIClicked: amIClicked);
}

class _ListItemCardState extends State<ListItemCard> {
  int id;
  var callbackFunction;
  bool amIClicked;
  _ListItemCardState({this.callbackFunction, this.id, this.amIClicked = false});
  //here you finally get "amIClicked" variable with either false or true
  //Based on that , you can show different colors to your card clicked and 
  //-non-clicked
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: callbackFunction(id),
      child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Container(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      widget.item,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red))),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I thought there will be some direct way to perform that.

Answer (score 0):

use provider from child card all your changes will request the parent list to redraw. if any thing changes in card the list will notify

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).